# PHP SAX parser for HTML?

Tags: php, sax, html-parsing

I need HTML SAX (not DOM!) parser for PHP able to process even invalid HTML code.
The reason i need it is to filter user entered HTML (remove all attributes and tags
except allowed ones) and truncate HTML content to specified length.

Any ideas?

Comment: hi, i am currently searching for such myself. i wonder if you are still using HTML SAX Parser, or if you've found something else?

Comment: Tidy is the unique "general solution" for "invalid HTML code", and PHP have a *build-in good SAX* (!) see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17903058/287948).

Comment: See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15679103/287948

Answer (score 4):

SAX was made to process valid XML and fail on invalid markup. Processing invalid HTML markup requires keeping more state than SAX parsers typically keep.

I'm not aware of any SAX-like parser for HTML. Your best shot is to use to pass the HTML through tidy before and then use a XML parser, but this may defeat your purpose of using a SAX parser in the first place.

Comment: even after tidy pieces of HTML won't be valid. they're like this:
`some comment with <b>bold text</b>, <i>italic text</i>.`

it's invalid document for any XML parser. there's no root, but i don't want to mess around with wrapping content with some root element.

Comment: @Daniel why do you need an event handler in the first place. If the HTML snippets are short, I see no compelling reason.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, I meant an event driven API such as SAX.

Comment: oh, i've already got implementation using SAX parser, it's very efficient and simple, but its problem is SAX parser itself. it uses regexp to parse HTML :(

Comment: @Daniel HTML parsing with regex => trouble

Comment: agree. thats why i'm looking for something better.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [HTML SAX Parser](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2140-PHP-Parse-HTML-documents-using-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: I've tried to use it, it can't handle embedded js or complex styles because its based on regexes.

Comment: I used it to solve the problem that you are trying to solve. I filter user-generated content, cut JavaScript, tags, attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing as two steps:

1. Use *Tidy* to transform "free HTML" into "good XHTML".
2. Use *XML Parser* to parse XHTML as XML by *SAX API*.

---

Use first [Tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.tidy.php) (!), to transform "free HTML" into XHTML (or when you can not trust your "supposed XHTML"). See [cleanRepair](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.cleanrepair.php) method. It needs more time, but runs with big files (!)... [Set some minutes as maximum execution time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) if too big.

Another option (for work with big files) is to cache your XHTML files after checked or transformed into XHTML. See Tidy's [repairfile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairfile.php) method.

With a "trusted XHTML", *use SAX*... How to use SAX with PHP?

Parse XML with a [SAX standard API](http://www.saxproject.org), that in PHP is implemented by [LibXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.libxml.php) (see *LibXML2* at [xmlsoft.org](http://www.xmlsoft.org/)), and its interface is the [PHP's XML Parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php), that is near to the *SAX standard API*.

Another way to use the "SAX of *LibXML2*", with another interface (a [PHP iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) instead the traditional SAX interface), is to use [XMLReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php). See [this explanation about "XMLReader use SAX"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3048490/287948).

---

Yes, the terms "SAX" or "SAX API" not expressed in the PHP manual (!!).  See   [this old but good introduction](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch12_05.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest the pear package here : http://pear.php.net/package/XML_HTMLSax/redirected