# PHP not have access to the LibXML2 SAX interface?

Tags: php, xml, saxparser

PHP not have a "[standard SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML)" interface for *event-driven XML parse*, [have a Expat one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xml.requirements.php). *Expat* require `--enable-libxml` option... But [LibXML2 have a good and fast standard SAX interface](http://www.xmlsoft.org/interface.html) (!)... So, **how to access the LibXML2's *standard SAX interface* with PHP?**

There are a simple workaround to enable the SAX interface?

---

Related question: [Is XMLReader a SAX parser, a DOM parser, or neither?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3048437/287948)

**Terminology** (to say the "same language" in the discussions):

- *event-driven XML parser*: SAX and Expat, they was 1998's "competidors", but today (2013's) are only a "reference model for interfacing the parser implementation".
- *event-driven XML parser* implementations: see [LibXML2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/), [expat.sourceforge](http://expat.sourceforge.net/), [Oracle/Java/SAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?org/xml/sax/package-summary.html), etc. They are "concrete implementations" (can generate binary code for the parser).
- *SAX interface*: an abstraction based on the "SAX reference model", see [saxproject.org](http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML).
- *Expat interface*: an abstraction based on the "Expat reference model", see [jclark.com/xml](http://www.jclark.com/xml/expatfaq.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expat_(XML)).
- PHP's [XML Parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php) conventions for an *event-driven XML parser interface*... **Is a Expat interface** but, it is over the *Expat* or the *LibXML2* implementation??
- *PHP's SAX interface*: not exist (!), but can be build as more one LibXML2 interface?
- PHP's "other XML parser interfaces": remember that [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), [XSLTProcessor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php), etc. are PHP interfaces to the LibXML2 implementations.

PS: please edit this text for better or detailed explanations... Detailing "library interface": is a set of function names, methods and properties, used as "module interface" between PHP (for programmers abstrations) and a library implementation (drivers, etc. for assembler/binary concrete implementation).

Comment: You are most likely looking for `XMLReader`. http://php.net/XMLReader

Comment: No, see [my link above](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xml.requirements.php): it is about XMLReader (!) and shows that XMLReader **is Expat**... Both (SAX and Expat) are event-driven parsers, but I prefer the SAX interface than Expat, and the LibXML2 (apparently faster!) reuse than use of another lib.

Comment: No you misread that. XML Parser is Expat (by default). XMLReader is just libxml so I thought it might use SAX of it internally. In any case, if you need the SAX methods directly, you need to create your own binding to them. AFAIK no binding so far exists, but I have not researched specifically as this was not necessary for me so far. -- Related Q&A: [Is XMLReader a SAX parser, a DOM parser, or neither?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3048437/367456)

Comment: Thanks (!). I edited, adding your link and "Terminology", to avoid more confusions.