# PHP - Read and repair big invalid XML files

Tags: php, xml, sax

I have to read some quite heavy XML files (between 200 MB and 1 GB) that are, for some of them, invalid. Let me give you a small example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
  <item>
    <title>Some article</title>
    <g:material><ul><li>50 % Coton</li><li>50% Lyocell</li></g:material>
  </item>
</rss>
```

Obviously, there is a missing `</ul>` closing tag in the `g:material` tag. Moreover, people that have developed this feed should have enclosed `g:material` content into `CDATA`, which they did not... Basically, that's what I want to do : add this missing `CDATA` section.

I've tried to use a SAX parser to read this file but it fails when reading the `</g:material>` tag since the `</ul>` tag is missing. I've tried with XMLReader but got basically the same issue.
I could probably do something with DomDocument::loadHtml but the size of this file is not really compatible with a DOM approach.
Do you have any idea how I could simply repair this feed without having to buy lots of RAM for DomDocument to work ?
Thanks.

Comment: yes they should have done it. you could always try to regexp find/replace all your files if you know where the problems are. but it should not have been your concern at first place.

Comment: Hey Rémi, couldn't you read the string, hence adding the CDATA sections, before you push it to your xml loader?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking about and what I am doing right now but I still hope there is better thinks to do than reading XML character by character or do find/replace with regexp :)

Comment: See similar (oldest) question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2939250/287948

Answer (score 3):

If the files are too large to use the [Tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) extension, you can use the [tidy CLI tool](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tidy) to make the files parseable.

```
$ tidy -output my.clean.xml my.xml
```

After that, the XML files are well-formed, so you can parse them using the XMLReader. Since tidy adds the 'missing' (X)HTML parts, your original document's code is inside the  element.

Comment: ops, you can use Tidy extension for big files (see my answer below). And you can use PHP as a command for transform HTML files into XHTML by terminal.

Answer (score 0):

(copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17903058/287948)

Summarizing as two steps:

1. Use *Tidy* to transform "free HTML" into "good XHTML".
2. Use *XML Parser* to parse XHTML as XML by *SAX API*.

---

Use first [Tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.tidy.php) (!), to transform "free HTML" into XHTML (or when you can not trust your "supposed XHTML"). See [cleanRepair](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.cleanrepair.php) method. It needs more time, but runs with big files (!)... [Set some minutes as maximum execution time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) if too big.

Another option (for work with big files) is to cache your XHTML files after checked or transformed into XHTML. See Tidy's [repairfile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairfile.php) method.

With a "trusted XHTML", *use SAX*... How to use SAX with PHP?

Parse XML with a [SAX standard API](http://www.saxproject.org), that in PHP is implemented by [LibXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.libxml.php) (see *LibXML2* at [xmlsoft.org](http://www.xmlsoft.org/)), and its interface is the [PHP's XML Parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php), that is near to the *SAX standard API*.

Another way to use the "SAX of *LibXML2*", with another interface (a [PHP iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) instead the traditional SAX interface), is to use [XMLReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php). See [this explanation about "XMLReader use SAX"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3048490/287948).

---

Yes, the terms "SAX" or "SAX API" not expressed in the PHP manual (!).  See   [this old but good introduction](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch12_05.htm).